# Does rust-tui provide any mouse functionality above Termion?

Tags: rust, tui, rust-tui

Rust TUI provides things like tabs and widgets. But they can't be clicked on. Termion supports this. Is there anyway to get click events to work in rust-tui's widgets?

Some other toolkits like [blessed.js](https://github.com/chjj/blessed) support this too.

I grepped the source code for "click" and couldn't find any examples of this.

Answer (score 1):

Digging around this is an already-filed enhancement request.

- https://github.com/fdehau/tui-rs/issues/166

The Rust-tui widgets do not support click events.